How to prove irrationality of a decimal expansion of 1's and 0's in differing bases
Suppose we have an decimal expansion of an irrational number - say, $\pi$ - in binary, which will look something like 11.001001...
Now, if we keep those 1's and 0's, but look at them in base 10, so that, in base 10 - rather than 3.14... - we have 11.001001...
I would've thought that this decimal expansion is still irrational when viewed in base 10 rather than binary, but how could you prove it?
Apologies if that's not clear, so, to rephrase my question in another way:
If, for some $\mathrm{A} \subset \mathbb{N}_0$,
$\sum_{i=0} ^{\infty} $$_\mathrm{A}(i)\frac{1}{2^i}$
is irrational, how can you prove that
$\sum_{i=0} ^{\infty} $$_\mathrm{A}(i)\frac{1}{10^i}$
is also irrational?
Presumably a proof of this could easily be extended for any bases?

Not sure what you are asking.  Whether a number is rational or not has nothing to do with any base.  And, again in any base, rational is the same as having an eventually periodic expansion.

As @lulu says, this sequence of digits is not eventually periodic, so it represents an irrational number in any base. The usual base 10 expansion of $\pi$ represents an irrational number in any base $b \ge 10$.

Thank you both!

The rule "As a decimal a rational number terminates or eventually repeats over and over again, while an irrational decimal goes on forever and never repeats" is true for any base.  So $\pi$ is irrational means its binary expansion goes on forever and never repeats.  If we take the string we get and treat it as decimal (so our number is just a little more than eleven) it goes on forever and never repeats.  So whatever the number represents (nothing noteworthy other than being a translation of $\pi$, I'd guess) it is irrational.

Rational numbers terminate and repeat in base $b$ simply because when you divide an integer by $b$ you have only $b$ possible remainders.  When expanding if you "hit" a remainder that you've already come across everything is as it was the first time you came across it so everything that happens next will happen exactly as it did before. (unless the remainder is $0$ in which case it terminates). That is why the rule works. The proof... well, that's tedious but google "why rational decimals repeat". They'll mostly be about base ten but it should be clear the arguments are the same for all bases.

... oh.  because you have only $b$ possible remainders you will have to come across a remainder you've come across before within $b$ iterations (or you will get remainderless division and it will terminate)....
